# How to use ajax without a form?

Tags: 8, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to setup a ajax call with JS but without building a drupal form. Basically it will trigger when the user clicks a specific class element on the page.

I've looked through the documentation but it seems to only be talking about ajax with drupal forms. Is this the only way to setup a ajax callback? I will link my code below.

The code itself works when I click my element. I get hello world. But i'm trying to figure out how to setup a drupal js ajax callback but it keeps saying I need to make a form.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {


  Drupal.behaviors.modals = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#ajax-dashboard-display--erc360_academic_institution_dashboard', context).each(function () {
        // Create HTML markup
        let container = document.createElement('div');
        container.setAttribute('class', 'dashboard-container-modals');
        let modal = document.createElement('div');
        modal.setAttribute('class', 'dashboard-modal');
        container.appendChild(modal);
        let image = document.createElement('div');
        image.setAttribute('class', 'document-modal-img');
        modal.appendChild(image);
        let status = document.createElement('div');
        status.setAttribute('class', 'document-modal-status activitycircle activitycirclegreen');
        modal.appendChild(status);
        let myTarget = document.getElementById('ajax-dashboard-display--erc360_academic_institution_dashboard');
        myTarget.appendChild(container);
        $(".dashboard-modal").animate({right: '-100px'},800);

        $('.document-modal-status').click(function(){
          alert("hello world");
        })




      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: Also see [Ajax Dialog Boxes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes)

Comment: `setup a drupal js ajax callback but it keeps saying I need to make a form.` what keeps saying this? AJAX is not a Drupal specific thing, you can use it any way you'd like.